# how to install php 5.4 with ubuntu 16??

Tags: php, ubuntu, lamp

I have install LAMP stack on ubuntu 16, I got php 7.

I want to downgrade it to php 5.4 . what command should I use to remove php 7 and install php 5.4 in my ubuntu 16?

Comment: Have you tried one of the PHP version managers(switchers) available:
[phpbrew](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew), [php-version](https://github.com/wilmoore/php-version) or another?

Comment: Do you have a good reason for doing so? a) 5.4 is completely unsupported. and b) there is very little code that wont run on 7.0 c) 7.0 can be around 100% faster d) if nothing else use 5.6!

Comment: Don't do that. PHP 5.4 is dead, and it's not getting security updates any more, so you'll make your server not only outdated, but also vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

try this

sudo apt-get purge php*

then

sudo apt-get install php5.4 php5.4-gettext php5.4-common

Answer (score -1):

First, remove LAMP from your Ubuntu.
Then, use the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 mysql-server mysql-client php5-mysql //install php 5.3
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get remove php5 //remove php 5.3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5 //install php 5.4
```

Comment: it is not working and why are we removing php5 ? I have php7 in my system.

Comment: first ,you should remove php7 or LAMP , after did it, command this codes.

Answer (score -1):

First you must install PHP 5.4 (if you have not already done so):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-fpm php5-mysql
```

And then:

Apache:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0 ; sudo a2enmod php5.4 ; sudo service apache2 restart
```

CLI:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.4
```